# can not stop form, in any case

Tags: jquery, events, submit

I use this to stop from:

```
$("#searchform").submit(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

The problem is that if I use Ajax after this, submit form does not stop.
Anyone knows how to do ajax query without trigger again submit.

```
ajax_function(options){
    $.ajax(options);
}

$("#searchform").submit(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    ajax_function(options);
}
```

This code trigger form submit in Chrome

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` is usually not necessary.

Comment: Only way, I found, input element out of form tag

Answer (score 2):

```
ajax_function(options){
$.ajax(options);
}
```

must be

```
function ajax_function(options) {
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

Otherwise it's a syntax error and your event is never registered.